# Shell how to test if item is present in list and affect the result in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

i ve a shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
server=$1
modules=$2  #example of modules = moduleOne,moduleTwo,moduleThree   

is_selected=$( if [[ $modules == *"moduleThree"* ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi)
```

I want that if "**moduleThree**" is present in the list $modules which may change :

**examples :**

```
modules = moduleOne,moduleTwo,moduleThree   
modules = moduleOne,moduleThree,moduleFour
modules = moduleOne
```

Like that i get the result always as false

**How may i correct it ?**

Comment: You are missing a `]]` in your command. Is that a typo in the question, or the root of your problem?

Comment: @chepner just a wrong copy paste to the question , but that do exist , and that's not working

Comment: Do you have a space between the `*` and `]]`?

Comment: Cn you redesign the interface so that instead of using `./script server moduleOne,moduleTwo,moduleThree` you use `./script server moduleOne moduleTwo moduleThree`, providing the list of modules as separate words.  It will be easier to work with the module names if they're provided separately.

Comment: @chepner yes i do have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bash regex with `=~`

```
#!/bin/bash
server=$1
modules=$2  #example of modules = moduleOne,moduleTwo,moduleThree

re='.*moduleThree.*'
[[ $modules =~ $re ]] && is_selected='true' || is_selected='false'
echo $is_selected
```

Usage

```
$ ./test srv moduleOne,moduleTwo
false

$ ./test srv moduleOne,moduleThree,moduleTwo
true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a comma-separated string, use that to populate an array, then scan the array for the correct module.

```
IFS=, read -a module_list <<< "$2"

is_selected=false; for mod in "${module_list[@]}"; do [[ $mod = moduleThree ]] && is_selected=true; done
```

If you plan to check the list for multiple modules, it would make sense to create an associative array from `module_list`, so that you can do lookups in constant time:

```
declare -A mod_array
for mod in "${module_list[@]}"; do
  mod_array[$mod]=
done

mod_three_selected=false; [[ -v mod_array[moduleThree] ]] && mod_three_selected=true
```

Unless you need the value of `mod_three_selected` for something like a configuration file, it will be simpler to just use your array directly:

```
if [[ -v mod_array[moduleThree] ]]; then
    ....
fi
```

rather than

```
if [[ mod_three_selected = true ]]; then
    ....
fi
```

Comment: i got Syntax that  : error: redirection unexpected , it seems that it hangs on : IFS=, readarray -a module_list <<< "$2"

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`?

Comment: yeah i run it with sh myscript.sh

Comment: `sh` isn't `bash` on your machine; I'm guessing you use Ubuntu, in which case `sh` is `dash`. The shebang is ignored when you use `sh myscript.sh`.

Comment: i m running shell script inside jenkinspipleine , so that i mys run it that way , there is no possibility to adapt it with shell ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to correctly identify the shell you need a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to actually be using `bash`, so you need to stick with POSIX-compliant constructs.

```
case $2 in
  moduleThree,*|,moduleThree,|*,moduleThree) is_selected=true ;;
  *) is_selected=false
esac
```

Comment: as i said , modules may vary -> examples ->  : modules = moduleOne,moduleTwo,moduleThree   
modules = moduleOne,moduleThree,moduleFour
modules = moduleOne